# create a rename textfield at a treeview item

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, textfield, scene

I made e treeview structure with items and maps in it.

Now i want to make an option so that i can rename the items.
I want to make a textfield popup at the node when i use a contextmenu to rename it.
I got suckt at a couple points.

First im not sure how to display the textfield over the treeview.

Second , im not sure how to position it correctly

this is the method that is called when i want to rename.
im trying to add the textfield to the borderpane that holds the treeview.

```
    javafx.scene.control.MenuItem renameButton = new javafx.scene.control.MenuItem("Rename");
    toRootButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            TextField renameField = new TextField();
            mainBorderPane.getChildren().add(renameField);

            renameField.relocate(treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getGraphic().getLayoutX(),treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getGraphic().getLayoutY());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you not just make the `TreeView` editable?  See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623802/edit-item-in-javafx-treeview).

Comment: thx , ill try that